# Android - How to stack the views added dynamically?

Tags: java, android, view

I'm a newcomer on Android and in the Google Guide I'm in this part: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html.

Yes, it's about the dabatase, but to put it in practice, in my dummy studying app I created a simple system for store "profiles" to have something to store in the database. Basically, I've created an Activity for fill some text fields and store it in the database. And a class called ProfileDao that do the CRUD stuff.

I've reached a point where I want to build an activity to show all profiles added, using a LinearLayout. The problems is that I can't stack the views in code as the XML does.

Here is some code:
The ProfileFragment class:

```
public final class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    private String _name;
    private String _gender;
    private int _age;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View retVal = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container, false);
        final TextView _nameField = (TextView) retVal.findViewById(R.id.profile_fragment_name);
        final TextView _genderField = (TextView) retVal.findViewById(R.id.profile_fragment_gender);
        final TextView _ageField = (TextView) retVal.findViewById(R.id.profile_fragment_age);

        _nameField.setText(_name);
        _genderField.setText(_gender);
        _ageField.setText(String.valueOf(_age));

        return retVal;
    }

    public void setName(String name) { _name = name; }
    public void setGender(String gender) { _gender = gender;}
    public void setAge(int age) { _age = age; }

    public String getName() { return _name; }
    public String getGender() { return _gender; }
    public int getAge() { return _age; }
}
```

My intent initially was to use this fragment to dinamically put it in a LinearLayout, but I quickly saw I can't do this and made this class just a util for return a view.

The SeeProfilesActivity:

```
public class SeeProfilesActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = makeLogTag(SeeProfilesActivity.class);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.see_profiles_activity);

        final ProfileDao profDao = new ProfileDao(new ProfileDbHelper(this));
        final List<Profile> profiles = profDao.getProfiles();
        LOGD(TAG, "PROFILES RETRIEVED");

        if(profiles.size() == 0) {
            final TextView thereisNotProfiles = new TextView(this);
            thereisNotProfiles.setText(getString(R.string.there_is_not_profiles));
            thereisNotProfiles.setTextSize(35);

            LOGD(TAG, "NO PROFILES, SO JUST DISPLAY THERE IS NOT");

            setContentView(thereisNotProfiles);
            return;
        }

        addFragmentProfiles(profiles);
    }

    private void addFragmentProfiles(List<Profile> profiles) {
        final LinearLayout itLayout = (LinearLayout) ((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
        itLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        View currView;

        for(Profile prof : profiles) {
            final ProfileFragment profFrag = new ProfileFragment();

            profFrag.setName(prof.getName());
            profFrag.setGender(prof.getGender());
            profFrag.setAge(prof.getAge());

            LOGD(TAG, "WELL, ONE PROFILE WAS RETRIEVED");

            currView = profFrag.onCreateView(getLayoutInflater(), itLayout, null);
            itLayout.addView(currView);//here is my problem
            LOGD(TAG, "SUCCESS IN DISPLAY");
        }

    }
}
```

How do I reproduce the behaving of stacking the views present in a LinearLayout XML in code?

Before some objections:

- I know some of you will say there's a better way to do it, mainly the experient developers (maybe saying I can use ListView with adapters. Yes, I know it, but I didn't reach this part of the guide yet). But, get the fact I'm a very fresh beginner and really want to do this by hand to enjoy the maximum of what a learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the fragment layout "profile_fragment" height is wrap_content,not fill or match parent.
My english is not well,I hope you can understand ....

R.Layout.profile_fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" // This is your problem.
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: =OOOOO, god! It worked! Hahha, sorry for the question. My error was just looking just in the code.